# prototype programmatic style sheet

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs

Excuse the naivete of this but I have defined styles and upon a button click I would like to assign a style to an element.  The target element is `"msg00"` and I cannot determine what attribute of that to pick to assign the desired style sheet.
`$$('id="msg00"').style="start";` knowable wrong.  Also how would this be different in jQuery?  Which I could migrate to.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a *CSS class* to an element? How did you define the style?

Comment: @FelixKling
I am asking how to select an element and assign it a defined internal style sheet.  I have used the $("elementName").attribute before.  Firstly I would like to know the syntax to assign a new style sheet after page load.  Secondarily I would like to know the syntax to search for a parametrized element and then assign an attribute.

Comment: @cp. - the style sheet is the entire definition of all the styles - all the elements. It's almost like the actual `css` file that was loaded. You can change individual element's style without swapping the whole css file.

Comment: we more foten add a class onto the element that moves it into coverage by existing CSS rules

Comment: Yeah, a style sheet is the whole set of CSS rules you created. You don't assign a style sheet to an element. The style sheet is loaded into the document and specific rules are associated with elements via the selectors. It really isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: If you have a question about jQuery then start a new question (or read old ones) since the answer will be different.  It doesn't help anyone to mix different answers together.

Answer (score 0):

`$$('id="msg00"')` is bad syntax.  The preferred way of finding a single element by an ID is with [`$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/)

```
$('msg00') // returns a single element
```

The general way of finding elements by their attribute is with an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).  But this returns an array so you cannot access it's `style` property, or any other, directly.  You would have to resort to any of the [Array](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/) or [Enumerable](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/) methods.

```
$$('[id=msg00]') // returns an array of elements
```

---

Now to assign a style to an element which has been found you can use the convenient [`Element#setStyle`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/setStyle/) method.

```
$('msg00').setStyle({
    backgroundColor: 'red'
});
```

As an example here is the same effect but for all `msg*` elements.

```
// this selector means an ID which starts with "msg"
$$('[id^=msg]').invoke('setStyle', {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
});
```